# Why is my app.use executing 21 times per request?

Tags: node.js, express

I was trying to debug my code in a node.js server and suddenly I found something very odd, the app.use callback function gets executed 21 times per every navigator request, which is the oddest thing I have seen.

Now, I am new to node, is this something usual? You would ask me how I noticed this, I basically set a counter variable initialized on 0 named `request`, and I increase it by one for every execution of the callback and print it in the address bar to check the current value, and every time I visit localhost the counter increases by 21 meaning there are 21 consecutive callbacks..any ideas?

```
//libraries
var app = require('express')(),
    http = require('http').Server(app),
    express = require('express'),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    path = require('path'),
    logger = require('morgan'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');
//custom
var databases = require('../common/config/databases'),
    reactivity = require('./reactivity/init'),
    requestValidator = require('./middleware/validateRequest.js'),
    apiConfig = require('./routes/api.js');

//ROUTING
app.all('/api/v1/*', [requestValidator]);//check /api/v1/* requests for an authenthic token

app.use('/', apiConfig);

var request = 0;
app.use(function (req, res, next) {//404
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    request += 1;
    res.redirect('#404' + request);
    next();
});

app.set('port', 4000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
        console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
    });
```

Comment: Why are you redirecting on 404? and more, why would you redirect to #404? is that an angular route or something? is there some kind of redirect loop happening?

Comment: oh I see you are right there might be a loop there, and yes it is an angularjs route, I will check further on the possibility of a loop

Comment: in theory, the only 404's you'll have are ones from your api routes, and static assets. so redirecting to an angular route wouldn't be that helpful anyway. an asset 404 is likely what is failing here.